# if statement is giving the same output the first part of the IF works if there's value in the input box it doesn't show the correct message

Tags: javascript, cordova, geofencing

The function is giving the same output for both cases what am i doing wrong?

```js
function showToast() {
  if (document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML == "") {
    window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions({
      message: "Geofence perimeter has been correctly set. \n \n Hence you may now proceed with Geofence Activation",
      duration: "short",
      position: "top",
    }, );
  } else if (!document.getElementById("latitude".innerHTML == "")) {
    window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions({
      message: "Geofence perimeter cannot be set due to missing configuration \n \n Kindly update all fields accordingly",
      duration: "short",
      position: "top",
    }, );
  }
}
```

Comment: What are both the case? Probably you have misplaced the closing parenthesis in `else if()`

Comment: Voting to close a typo-type. Input fields have .value, not .innerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That if in the else is not needed
Also you could have used !== instead of !something == ""

Lastly if document.getElementById("latitude") is an input field you need to test the ***.value***, not innerHTML

Please use a ternary. Note the `?` and colon `:`

```js
function showToast() {
  const empty = document.getElementById("latitude").value.trim() === "" // to be sure it is empty
  const message = empty ? 
     "Geofence perimeter has been correctly set. \n \n Hence you may now proceed with Geofence Activation" : 
     "Geofence perimeter cannot be set due to missing configuration \n \n Kindly update all fields accordingly"
  window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions({
    message: message,
    duration: "short",
    position: "top"
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i tried your answer but still it didnt work, im still getting the same output "Geofence perimeter cannot be set due to missing configuration \n \n Kindly update all fields accordingly"  empty or not, also what do you mean by "Please use a ternary. Note the ? and colon :"

Comment: I mean this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Also if my code does not work, then the test is not correct. So document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML === "" is not correct test. What is the aim of the test and are you sure it is the empty string? Perhaps you need `document.getElementById("latitude").textContent.trim() === ""`

Comment: My aim is to check whether the input field is empty or not. Sort of like a validation pretty much using IONIC inputs. So if the inputs are empty and the user clicks a button a TOAST should pop up and say it's empty and can't proceed... If the inputs are filled in a toast should pop out with a positive message

Comment: SO document.getElementById("latitude") is an INPUT field? Then you need .value not innerHTML!!